# Hashmap with pointer as values

Tags: c++

I want to create an unordered map in c++ with 'key' as an integer but the 'value' is a pointer to a vector.How should I declare such a map and use it
to access elements of the vector?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<Type>*> mymap;
```

or better:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<std::vector<Type>>> mymap;
```

Access it like:

```
auto vptr = mymap[10];
```

Comment: If I want to insert an entry into the hastable mymap, is it the right way of doing so?    auto ptr=dictionary // dictionary is the name of the vector       mymap[value]=ptr;

Comment: Well yes, if ptr is a pointer to a vector. Example:
vector<int>* v = new vector<int>;
mymap[value] = v;